# Unrolling an ...args array in a function call

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm making numerous ExternalInterface calls to JavaScript methods and have a helper function for doing so:

```
protected function JSCall( methodName:String, ...args ):void
{
  try
  {
    ExternalInterface.call( methodName, args );
  }
  … etc …
}
```

However this means the JavaScript method will only be passed one argument - the array of arguments - meaning I have to change the JavaScript to accomodate this, e.g. instead of:

```
function example(argument1, argument2)
{

}
```

I end up with:

```
function example(args)
{
  var argument1 = args[0];
  var argument2 = args[1];
}
```

What I'd love to do is unroll the arguments array being passed to the `JSCall` method so that each argument is passed individually to the `ExternalInterface` call, such that:

```
JSCall('example', ['one', 'two'])
```

works like:

```
ExternalInterface.call('example', 'one', 'two')
```

Answer (score 3):

To call a javascript function from flash with multiple arguments, all you have to do is:

```
ExternalInterface.call.apply(null, [functionName, arg1, arg2, ..., argn]);
```

If you're taking the arguments from a variable list of arguments of another function, then you can use:

```
function JSCall(methodName:String, ...args):void
{
    if (ExternalInterface.available){
        args.unshift(methodName);
        ExternalInterface.call.apply(null, args);
    }

    //btw, you can do the same with trace(), or any other function
    args.unshift('Calling javascript function');
    trace.apply(null, args);
}
```

Somewhere else you would call:

```
JSCall('console.log', 'Testing', 123, true, {foo:'bar'});
```

...which would print something like `Testing 123 true Object` on your firebug/webkit console.

This is tested and works for sure, as I'm using it in a real project.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Cameron, have you tried using Function.apply()? Try this:

```
ExternalInterface.call.apply( methodName, args );
```

It's so crazy, it just might work!

Comment: This indeed works, it's ingenious hack, I myself have used it a couple of times now, looks strange and 90% of the people don't understand it when they see it for the first time but hey it's awesome!

Comment: Hi Mims/Ivo, unfortunately while this doesn't cause any compile/run-time Flash errors, it's raising JavaScript errors when trying to execute the EI call. @Ivo - do you have a real example of using this technique?

Comment: From looking at the API documentation for apply(), I can see how the following would work: `ExternalInterface.call.apply(null, [methodname, args])` but that's the same as directly using ExternalInterface.call which doesn't help ;)

Comment: I wonder if this would work:
＇ExternalInterface.call( method.apply, args);＇

Comment: Also, and I mean no disrespect, perhaps you should ask yourself whether you're saving yourself any trouble by approaching it this way. If you're just doing it to avoid having to add the try catch statement, maybe put it inline. If there's lots of code, you could call something like prepForJSCall() then do ExternalInterface.call().

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this `Function.call.apply(foo, [that, test, bla])` works like `foo.call(that, test, bla)` but since `ExternalInterface.call` is not equal to `Function.prototype.call` we need to use a different approach here.

```
// Let's fake ExternalInterface
var funcs = {
    example: function(arg1, arg2) {
        console.log(arg1, arg2);
    }
};

var ExternalInterface = {};
ExternalInterface.call = function() {
    var f = funcs[arguments[0]];
    f.call.apply(f, arguments);
}


// This does crazy stuff.
function JSCall(func, args) {
    args.unshift(func);
    ExternalInterface.call.apply(ExternalInterface, args);
}

// These do the same now
ExternalInterface.call('example', 'one', 'two'); // one two
JSCall('example', ['one', 'two']); // one two
```

Note: I have not tested this in ActionScript.